# Display time left when running

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a few buttons which execute code when pressed like running validations on the database.

Some code can run for a few minutes so is there any way to show the time remaining or a message to display the % of process completed?

Or pop out a message when code evaluation starts and the message should disappear once code running is completed?

Comment: btw. consider marking some of the answers you've been given as "accepted". Its the currency of Stack Overflow. It earns you rep and it earns us rep, By not doing so, you are effectively encouraging us NOT to answer your questions.

Comment: i was not aware of that. I ll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is a "Progress Bar".

I've used the Microsoft ProgressBar control (you can find it under Insert->ActiveX Control), and it's not that hard to use. Just set the value of it to a percentage (as an integer, not a decimal).

```
'foo, being the ProgressBar
me.foo = 70 '70%
```

There is some good info here on another method: http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/progressbar.htm

Comment: Tony's SysCmd method is far preferable, seems to me, as it uses built-in Access controls, instead of introducing a dependency on an outside ActiveX control.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this the "normal" way, you'd need to run your validation in another thread and have it report its progress back to the UI thread.  However, I don't believe VBA supports any kind of multithreading.

If your validation routines involve a loop, or even just many separate discrete operations, you can try inserting a `DoEvents` statement in between loop iterations (or operations), and then have your progress display updated periodically (say, in an `Application_OnTime` event handler).

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a form I name frmProgress or whatever, with a cancel button and a label for displaying a status message.  Then embedded in the form code I have a boolean called bCancel, and when you hit the cancel button it simply sets bCancel as true.

Also in this code I have a routine called ShowPercDone( Idx , NumIdc ) where Idx is the step the code is on, and NumIdc is the number of steps the code will take (assuming each step takes the same amount of time). This works well when I'm running through a for loop, but basically any time I want to display a status update I just call the routine in the form with my message, which I should add runs the doevents command for me.

So that's how the status form works. In the macro I run, I start out by just calling frmProgress.show (0) so that it lets you click the cancel button.  Then in my loop when I update the status message I then check frmProgress.bCancel and if it's true I exit out of the macro.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally to be simple i decided to use the method given here

http://oreilly.com/pub/h/3330#code